# Bash: remove numbers at the end of names.

Tags: bash, file-rename

I have files like: 
alien-skull-2224154.jpg
snow-birds-red-arrows-thunderbirds-blue-angels-43264.jpg 
dead-space-album-1053.jpg

How can I remove in bash the "ID" string before .jpg
The id is always separated by the before word with "-"
Thanks.

Comment: And it is always just numbers? And they are the only numbers in the name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way using [bash parameter substitution](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/bash-shell-parameter-substitution-2.html):

```
for i in *.jpg; do mv "$i" "${i%-*}.jpg"; done
```

Or for the more general case (i.e. if you have other file extensions), try:

```
for i in *.*; do mv "$i" "${i%-*}.${i##*.}"; done
```

Results:

```
alien-skull.jpg
dead-space-album.jpg
snow-birds-red-arrows-thunderbirds-blue-angels.jpg
```

---

As per the comments below, try this bash script:

```
declare -A array

for i in *.*; do

    j="${i%-*}.${i##*.}"

    # k="$j"
    # k="${i%-*}-0.${i##*.}"

    for x in "${!array[@]}"; do

        if [[ "$j" == "$x" ]]; then
            k="${i%-*}-${array[$j]}.${i##*.}"
        fi
    done

    (( array["$j"]++ ))

    mv "$i" "$k"
done
```

Note that you will need to uncomment a value for `k` depending on how you would like to format the filenames. If you uncomment the first line, only the duplicate basenames will be incremented:

```
dead-space-album.jpg
dead-space-album-1.jpg
dead-space-album-2.jpg
dead-space-album-3.jpg
```

If you uncomment the second line, you'll get the following:

```
alien-skull-0.jpg
alien-skull-1.jpg
alien-skull-2.jpg
alien-skull-3.jpg
```

Comment: most optimized solution but assuming that u run in the same dir as jpg

Comment: your script worked fine except that if the resulting files with the same name will be overwritten, i would like to create an increment for each duplicate. thanks

Comment: @Mike: I've added a script for you. Simply choose how you'd like your filenames formatted. The first will do what you want. Please see the edit above. HTH.

Comment: @Steve can you help please? I am doing the same thing but your script is showing things like **mv: cannot move 'abstract-2100.jpg' to '': No such file or directory** even if there is that file in the same directory. I have double checked it. And also it's deleting one of the file in the process. only renaming 3 out of 10 files. Any idea please ?!

Comment: @TanmayaMeher, It's not that the file `abstract-2100.jpg` doesn't exist, it's that your replacement string is null. Check that the variable you're using as the destination in your `mv` command is set.

Comment: @Steve i have exactly copy pasted that script and kept it in the same folder as my images. not working still. When i am printing **j** it's fine showing every image name without numbers in the string. but when i print **k** it's only last 3 images name changed and all other blank lines as you said. so where do i change ? any idea?! :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming all file ID's are numbers you could use the rename command.

```
rename 's/-\d+//' *.jpg
```

This may not be available to every *nix, so here is a helpful link for alternatives:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/renaming-multiple-files-at-a-shell-prompt.html

Comment: Note that this uses the Debian style rename command, and not the util-linux version found on non-Debian derivatives.

Comment: @thatotherguy This is true.  I guess I put up the answer that I use on my machine :).

Comment: thanks ! that was fast and worked fine except that now I have encountered a problem what if the files with stripped id's are the same , how can i ad an increment like file.jpg, file-1.jpg file-2.jpg for each duplcate file. thanks.

Comment: i was thinking at this variant $j=0; for i in *.jpg; do let j+=1 ; mv "$i" "${i%-*}-$j.${i##*.}"; done   but the problem is with the increment step that is counting each file , not just the duplicates

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code that works great. Thank you all for your time!

```
for i in *.jpg; 
do

if [[  -e "${i%-*}.jpg" ]]; then
    num=1
    while [[ -e "${i%-*}-$num.jpg" ]]; do
        (( num++ ))
    done
 mv "$i" "${i%-*}-$num.jpg";

else 
rename 's/-\d+//' *.jpg
fi
 done
```

Comment: I think this will throw some errors regarding duplicate filenames. And it would only work with the `rename` utility. Please see my edit above.