# How to rename files from bash

Tags: bash

If I have a list of files all in a directory, how, from a bash terminal, can I change all the `-` in the names to something like `_`? I would also need to remove a pattern matching `_(Finker_2)`. This again should all be from the bash terminal.

Comment: Please check this questio 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928238/bash-file-rename

Comment: Also, please show what you've tried so far to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rename a file in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) you can do

```
mv oldFileName newFileName
```

If you want to do that for many files, you loop over them by

```
for file in *; do
    mv "$file" "${file//-/_}"
done
```

In this example we loop over all (`*`) files in the directory and rename them by replacing all occurrences of `-` with `_`.

Comment: _and rename them by replacing all occurrences of `-` with `_`_ is wrong: it'll only replace the first occurrence, if any. You need `"${file//-/_}"` to replace all occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

The `rename` command does that. You can use

```
# rename part replacement files
rename - _ *
```

It replaces the hyphens (`-`) in the name with underscores (`_`) in every file in the current directory.

Hope this helps.